# Joomla JToolbarhelper buttons dont work

Tags: button, joomla, controller, toolbar

I'm creating a custom component, but I can't get my toolbar to work.

view.html.php:

```
protected function addToolbar() {
    JToolBarHelper::title( JText::_('COM_CYCLIST_TITLE_CATEGORIES'), 'generic.png' );
    $bar = & JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
    $bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'new', 'JTOOLBAR_NEW', '/administrator/index.php?option=com_project&view=project&layout=edit');

    JToolbarHelper::addNew( 'project.add');
    JToolBarHelper::editList('project.edit');
    JToolBarHelper::deleteList('', 'projects.delete');

//        $bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'custom', 'Custom', '../index.php?option=com_mycomponent&format=raw' );

    }
```

Controller project.php:

```
<?php

// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.controlleradmin');

class ProjectControllerProject extends JControllerForm {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
?>
```

It doesn't matter what I provide as task for a toolbar button. When I press te button it opens the component url but it shows a 404. When I copy/paste the url in a new tab the overview will be shown.

http://localhostproject/administrator/index.php?option=com_project&view=projects

What am I missing?

**Administrator component:**
https://bitbucket.org/LightPhoenix/com_project/src

Comment: You should just give index.php?option=com_project&view=project&layout=edit as url

Comment: @Yoleth that works but I want to let it work based on the controller method. JToolbarHelper::addNew( 'project.add'); this isnt working, vardumping the controller shows the controller.

Comment: When clicking on a 'project.add' button, what is the url ?

Comment: @Yoleth /administrator/index.php?option=com_project&view=projects so basicly the overview url

Comment: Sorry for late response. Can you show code of your component base files, project.php and controller.php ?

Comment: @Yoleth no problem, I added a bitbucket link to my question, administrator/components. Maybe you can try it out on your computer to see what I am doing wrong. I'dd like to use the addNew, editList and deleteList method. But those don't recognise my controller for some reason.

Comment: Ok found it ! In your file views/projects/tmpl/default.php change line 54 to <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_project" />

Comment: @Yoleth thx a lot :) why does JToolBarHelper::deleteList('', 'projects.delete'); call the delete method in the model instead of the controller?

Comment: with this button joomla will call method delete of your controller, but if you don't override it in your own controller, it will call method from JControllerLegacy which will call model to delete.

Comment: @Yoleth I thought so but I keep getting this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method ProjectModelProjects::delete()

Comment: Change method public function getModel($name = 'Projects', $prefix = 'ProjectModel') to public function getModel($name = 'Project', $prefix = 'ProjectModel') (remove "s")

Comment: @Yoleth Thanks a lot :), I feel so stupid ...

Comment: So everything solved ?

Comment: @Yoleth Yup, thank you :) It was about a year ago I used joomla for the last time so I forgot a few things (a)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your addToolbar function to this

```
protected function addToolbar() {
    JToolBarHelper::title( JText::_('COM_CYCLIST_TITLE_CATEGORIES'), 'generic.png' );
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    // Run in backend
    if ($app->isAdmin() === true)
    {
        $bar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
        $url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_project&view=project&layout=edit');
        $bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'new', 'JTOOLBAR_NEW', $url);
    }

    JToolbarHelper::addNew( 'project.add');
    JToolBarHelper::editList('project.edit');
    JToolBarHelper::deleteList('', 'projects.delete');

    //$bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'custom', 'Custom', '../index.php?option=com_mycomponent&format=raw' );

}
```

Probabbly your url is incorrect so you are getting 404 error. If you use JRoute it will fix the url for you, if you are using sef url. $app->isAdmin() is to check if you are in Administrator Mode.

Comment: I don't use JRoute, the code you provided doesn't work for me :( the addNew button is still posting the overview instead of opening the creation page. edit/delete do not work either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that url is not correct of that popup. You should use joomla methods for Urls or start with index.php . If I am getting correctly, below code will work for you -

```
$bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'new', 'JTOOLBAR_NEW', Juri::base(true) . '/index.php?option=com_project&view=project&layout=edit');
```

OR

```
$bar->appendButton( 'Link', 'new', 'JTOOLBAR_NEW', 'index.php?option=com_project&view=project&layout=edit');
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, I would like to get the toolbar to work without a custom button. I'dd like to use the: JToolbarHelper::addNew( 'project.add'); method. I added a repo to my question.